# Autowire a bean only if it is available

Tags: java, spring

```
@Component
public class Test {
  @Autowire
  private MyBean myBean;

  public void sampleMethod()
  {
     if(myBean == null) {
       myBean = BeanFactory.getDefaultBean();
     }

     // ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to autowire `MyBean` if it is not defined in the spring configuration xml file? I understand that in this case, it would throw `No bean found of type MyBean`. Can we configure something to ignore that exception and fallback on the `BeanFactory` to get the `DeafultBean`.

Something like:

```
@Autowire(assignNullIfBeanNotFound = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at [the javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) (the annotation is named `Autowired`, and not `Autowire`):

> public abstract boolean required
>
> Declares whether the annotated dependency is required.
>
> Defaults to true.

Isn't this idea of providing documentation for classes wonderful?